# S3 serves gzipped assets. CloudFront does not. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I set up an Amazon S3 bucket for my static assets, and configured CloudFront to point to it. I have a Rails 4 app on Heroku.

When I set `config.action_controller.asset_host = "https://" + Figaro.env.FOG_DIRECTORY + ".s3.amazonaws.com"`, I get gzipped assets.

When I set `config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://" + Figaro.env.CLOUDFRONT_DIRECTORY + ".cloudfront.net"`, I don't get gzipped assets. Why not?

Comment: I have a similar problem:  our assets are on S3 via cloudfront.  If i ask for an asset (in curl) using just the url, i get the up to date version.  If i pass --compressed, i get an old version of it:  it's as if the compressed version (presumably created by s3 as cloudfront doesn't do any gzipping) is being cached somewhere, and when i pass --compressed i get that, not the new file.  Did you encounter this at all?

Comment: @MaxWilliams It has been several months, but no, I don't remember encountering this. I eventually replaced all my assets with gzipped versions with the same name--instead of "application.css" and "application.css.gz", I have "application.css" (a renamed gzipped file).

Comment: My problem turned out to be the S3 config:  it was set to "Custom Caching options" which for reasons which escape me at the moment meant that it wasn't serving the zipped resources properly.  Thanks for replying!

Comment: @MaxWilliams Sure, glad you got it working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

CloudFront can now compress files even if the origin server returns an uncompressed file. This only applies to [specific file types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html#compressed-content-cloudfront-file-types) that are between 1KB and 10MB. The full details are available at the original link that I posted below.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

CloudFront does not perform any compression/decompression on its own. If you have compressed files on S3 and uncompressed files in CloudFront, it's most likely a caching issue where CloudFront delivers an older, uncompressed, version of the files. Try to [invalidate](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html) those files on CloudFront.

You can learn more about CloudFront compression here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html

Comment: It was a caching issue. I deleted the CloudFront distribution and created a new one with the same S3 bucket and alternate domain names. Everything worked after my new distribution deployed and my DNS records updated. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, this has since been changed.
You can now enable CF to automatically compress some files:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html